# jQuery get the event for after document loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events

Need to find the event, after PDF document load or Focus the document.

```
window.onload

document.ready
```

These events are no used. did not fired on after loading document. Any way to get this event?

Comment: is pdf downloading in iframe inside page

Comment: Pdf loading inside the window. not iframe - Gokul kumar

Comment: My requirement is focus the document. once i am getting this event am executing the window focus using trigger click property inside the event.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your code?

Comment: am using PDFVIEWER control. so i open the pdf document using control. once pdf loaded need to get event.clear?